# How do I switch between views from another thread?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

I'm trying to use MVVM, so I have:

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="tbtest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddNewTab}" Grid.Row="1">Add new tab</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And ViewModel:

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        AddNewTab = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecAddNewTab);
    }

    private void ExecAddNewTab(object obj)
    {
        var tab = new SomeTab();
        Tabs.Add(tab.View);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(item => tab.Activate());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Object> Tabs { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand<object> AddNewTab { get; private set; }
}
```

Each tab is separate ViewModel with View:

```
public class SomeTab : ITab, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SomeTab()
    {
        View = new SomeTabView1 {DataContext = this};
    }

    public string Header { get { return "Header"; } }
    private object _view;
    public object View
    {
        get { return _view; }
        private set
        {
            _view = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("View"));
        }
    }

    public void Activate()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Some work

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<SomeTab>(vm =>
                                                                   {
// switching views, how can it be done?
                                                                          vm.View = new SomeTabView2 { DataContext = this };

                                                                   }), this);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

`SomeTabView1` And `SomeTabView2` are simple WPF UserControl with TextBlock 'View1' and 'View2'.

What I need is in Activate method (that is running in separate thread) switch View1 to View2.
This code I provided doesn't work.

What sould I do to get desired? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModels should not work with Views

Instead, have your `MainViewModel` contain a `SelectedTab` property and bind it to your `TabControl`, then to switch tabs you only set the `SelectedTab`. Use `DataTemplates` to tell WPF how to draw each ViewModel

MainWindow XAML

```
<Window x:Class="tbtest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local=clr-namespace:MyNamespace>

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTabViewModel1}">
            <local:SomeTabView1 /> 
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTabViewModel2}">
            <local:SomeTabView2 /> 
        </DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTabViewModel3}">
            <local:SomeTabView3 /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddNewTab}" Grid.Row="1">Add new tab</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow ViewModel

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
        AddNewTab = new DelegateCommand<object>(ExecAddNewTab);
    }

    private void ExecAddNewTab(object obj)
    {
        var tab = new SomeTab();
        Tabs.Add(tab);
        SelectedTab = tab;

        // This should only run whatever code is needed to initialize the
        // ViewModel. It should have nothing to do with views
        ((ITab)tab).Activate();
    }

    public object SelectedTab { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Tabs { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand<object> AddNewTab { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't need to switch tabs. All I need is switch view inside one tab. I need to: create new tab page, show on this tab page 'Loading...' message, load data iin background, show loaded data in the same tab (datagrids, textboxes, etc.)

Comment: In that case, your `TabViewModel` should have an `IsLoading` property that gets set to `true` when it gets activated, and the loading message and tab content's Visibility should be bound to `IsLoading`. Your ViewModels should never have to deal with Views

Comment: Thanks. Let's complicate the example. `MainWindowView` is in one assembly, and each `TabViewModel` in others. Now I have 10 different `TabViewModels`. Should I write in each(!) `TabView1`, `TabView2` the same code (binding to IsLoaded property and playing with Visibility)? Is it possible to create one common view `IsLoadingView` and display it, and then content loads, switch it to one of `TabViewXXX` view?

Comment: And how can I deal with `DataTemplates` (in your example in `Window.Resources`)? `MainWindowView` is in one assembly, and each `TabViewModel` and `TabViewXXX` in others? Where I need to write this code: `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SomeTabViewModel1}">
            <local:SomeTabView1 /> 
        </DataTemplate>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem above is due to the fact that your code is "assuming" that it will select \ focus the newly created `Tab` item by simply using `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`.

You need to back this field by a `CollectionView`. Also you should add new tab using this `CollectionView` itself.

E.g.

Assume you have a `ListCollectionView` called `TabsView` with source collection as `Tabs` observable collection...

Bind `TabControl.ItemsSource` to `TabsView` and then instead of ...

```
   var tab = new SomeTab();
   Tabs.Add(tab.View);
```

Use this...

```
   var tabUi = this.TabsView.AddNew() as SomeTab;
   this.TabsView.CommitNew();
   tabUi.Activate();
```

Let me know if this helps....

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. I don't need to select/focus the newly created tab item. I need, that tab content changes. First - I have to display 'Loading...' in tab view, and when all data is ready for display, I need to change view to DagaGrids, TextBoxes, etc...